# How to install jQuery on Mantis?

Tags: jquery, installation, mantis

Some plugins from [Mantis](https://www.mantisbt.org/addons.php) cannot be installed without first installing the jQuery plugin.

The Mantis-plugin control-panel says that there's a missing dependency: jQuery 1.8.

No matter where I put the jQuery .js file from [query.com/download/](https://jquery.com/download/), the message "*missing dependency: jQuery Library 1.8*" will not go away, and I cannot install the plugin.

Comment: OP is answering at the same time as the question is been posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is documented [here](https://www.mantisbt.org/bugs/view.php?id=16920) - but Google has trouble finding it.

Essentially, you have to install the **Mantis jQuery plugin** - which is not the same as what everybody else calls "jQuery ".

It can be downloaded at [github.com/mantisbt-plugins/jquery](https://github.com/mantisbt-plugins/jquery) and gets put in the Mantis' plugin folder.

After copying it and then installing it from the Mantis-plugin control-panel, the other plugin can be installed.

<sub>I hope this saves somebody time, it's the result of almost 2 hours of frustration.</sub>